# iOS Store varbinary from XML in Core Data

Tags: ios, xml, core-data, binary

I'm consuming an XML webservice in my iPad app and one of the elements in the XML is a varbinary(max) representation of an image stored in a SQL database.

I want to store that binary data in CoreData so that I can use the image in my app.

How would I best go about doing that?

Comment: Just read the varbinary in an NSData and save it using `value:forKey` in your `NSEntityDescription`

Answer (score 0):

Binary Data type with external storage seems like a good option, it was introduced in iOS 5. Though there was a [bug with migrations](http://www.nickkuh.com/iphone/core-data-migration-woes-with-binary-data-and-external-storage-data-loss/2012/06/), I am not sure if it was fixed.